Should pseudoabsences ever be sampled with replacement?
I have a question about the validity of building models using sampling of data with replacement. My spatial models predict the suitability of habitat for an animal, based on binary presence or absence of animals in each map pixel. As the sightings only record presence (no record is made if the beast was not seen), it is common practice to sample ‘pseudoabsences’ from across the study area, capturing the range of available environments that the animal could occupy.
Edit with a little more information about pseudoabsences and how they are treated: With a binary response variable, with a  ‘1’ recorded for presences, these pseudoabsences are each assigned a response of ‘0’. One might then fit something like a logistic regression. The ‘pseudo’ descriptor is because we do not truly know that the animal is absent from those places. This constrains how we can interpret the predicted values of the response; it is interpreted as a relative ranking of habitat suitability. <- End of edit.
One source of data for this kind of study is a database of public sightings, but animal sightings are biased to where there are many people. To correct for this sampling bias in the presence data, I planned to sample the pseudoabsences with the same (independently estimated) bias. Usually in this type of modelling, pseudoabsences are drawn without replacement, and each with equal chance of being sampled. In imposing sampling weights, I have encountered the problem that pixels that are highly frequented by people are quickly drawn down from the pool available for sampling. This means that pixels with few human visitors are ultimately over-represented in the sample of pseudoabsences, so that a spurious association of the study species with towns and cities is predicted.
One solution could be to draw the pseudoabsences with replacement (noting however that only one presence is ever recorded for each pixel, no matter how many times the animal has been spotted there, to improve spatial independence). Another solution could be to assign model weights so that pseudoabsences from locations far from towns are downweighted in the model estimation. What are the theoretical pros and cons of these approaches, or is there another way to adjust the pseudoabsences for sampling bias?

I don't fully understand the status and use of "pseudoabsences" here. I suspect answers will depend on fully understanding the model and how you intend to use it. This may well be an interesting problem, and beyond what you can expect to be delivered by asking random people for free on the internet.

A problem here is that these kinds of models based on resampling (assuming I understand this correctly) are theoretically different from the standard probability models in statistics. Theoretical "validity" may in some sense already be out of the window when formulating a model that actually depends on the available data. I have some work in biogeography that does such things, and I couldn't find much helpful theory in the statistics literature. It makes sense to think about the kind of problem you are mentioning here, and maybe something can be done, but I suspect it's not so easy.

Thanks @Christian for your swift reply. I may have to speak with a statistician in person then. I have edited my question to clarify a bit what I mean by pseudoabsences and how I intend to use them.

@ChristianHennig Yes, I see this as a form of resampling, and I am concerned about using it because of the theoretical differences I presume that brings. Did your exploration of the statistical literature unearth any references that spell out those differences? I have found a lot of material explaining other uses of resampling in crossvalidation, to obtain a measure of variation in some statistic, or for Monte Carlo etc., but to think critically about how resampling would affect my application, I feel I need some deeper understanding of its implications.

@ChristianHennig Could I invite you to expand on your sentence 'Theoretical "validity" may in some sense already be out of the window when formulating a model that actually depends on the available data'? What did you mean by a model that depends on the available data? Many thanks for your time.

Standard statistical theory is based on assuming a model with fixed and unknown parameters that generates the data. If you define your model by resampling from the data, theory about statistical implications would need to take into account that data are first used to define the model and then for the inference based on it. This is very hard. The term "parametric bootstrap" is used in the literature for this, and there isn't really much theory around. Several other uses of resampling have a theoretical basis assuming standard statistical models.

Some discussion can be found in this paper of mine with Chien-Ju Lin: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-015-9566-5 It has a biogeographical example in Sec. 5. Note that in order to understand what is going on, it is important to know how exactly the model will be used (the paper is about a specific use, as you will see). You can contact me directly via email if you are interested in a collaboration; I could probably contribute something, but it will take more time than I want to use for giving free advice here.

Thanks very much for your thoughts @ChristianHennig, I will read your paper with interest.

Both resampling and case weights can be used to adjust for sampling bias. Resampling tends to perform better in models that rely on stochastic gradient descent for their optimisation [1]. However, @ChristianHennig pointed out in the comments that  although resampling can be used to fit a model, using it to define the model is not well supported theoretically. If I understand this correctly, one could not use that resampled data for variable selection and model selection. If you already had a clear idea of the form of the model and just needed to estimate parameters, you could use a parametric bootstrap. The parametric bootstrap requires that the model is properly specified, and it is just a matter of finding the right parameter values [2]. That's not well suited for this application, where the identity of important predictors and the form of their relationship with the response is not well understood a priori.
An alternative that accommodates variable selection and model selection, as well as the ultimate model fit, is weighting the cases, using propensity weights [3]. Considering a manipulative experiment with two treatments, Control and Treatment, we can imagine that some cases are more likely to be allocated to the Treatment than the Control, and there are covariates we could use to predict this. Drawing on [4], the propensity score $\hat{e}$ is calculated as the log-odds of a case being allocated to the Treatment. Then, cases which received Treatment get propensity weights $w$ such that:
$w = 1 / \hat{e}$
And cases which received the Control get propensity weights:
$w = 1 / (1 - \hat{e})$
For my application, the species occurrences would get propensity weights proportional to the chance they were sampled. If the pseudoabsences are sampled at random, they all get equal weights.
A disadvantage of a weighting approach is that you may wind up with some very large weights, which in turn can lead to some very wide estimates of variance for the statistic of interest. There are some alternative approaches for managing that discussed in [5].
However, what I went for in the end was not to weight the cases or resample them, but to obtain pseudoabsences from presence records of other similar species. This ‘target species’ approach is widely used, if imperfect [6].
References
[1] An, J., Ying, L., & Zhu, Y. (2020). Why resampling outperforms reweighting for correcting sampling bias with stochastic gradients. arXiv preprint arXiv:2009.13447.
[2] Shalizi, C. S. (2013). Which bootstrap when? Statistics Department, Carnegie Mellon University. Retrieved June 9 from https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/13/lectures/which-bootstrap-when.pdf
[3] Mercer, A., Lau, A., & Kennedy, C. (2018). For weighting online opt-in surveys, what matters most? Pew Research. https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/2018/01/26/how-different-weighting-methods-work/
[4]  Olmos, A., & Govindasamy, P. (2019). A practical guide for using propensity score weighting in R. Practical assessment, research, and evaluation, 20(1), 13.
[5] Kostouraki, A., Hajage, D., Rachet, B., Williamson, E. J., Chauvet, G., Belot, A., & Leyrat, C. (2024). On variance estimation of the inverse probability‐of‐treatment weighting estimator: A tutorial for different types of propensity score weights. Statistics in Medicine.
[6] Ranc, N., Santini, L., Rondinini, C., Boitani, L., Poitevin, F., Angerbjörn, A., & Maiorano, L. (2017). Performance tradeoffs in target‐group bias correction for species distribution models. Ecography, 40(9), 1076-1087.
